# Why my MYSQL event scheduler stops every night at midnight?

Tags: mysql, laravel, events, nas, synology

So i have this database running on a Synology NAS, for a restaurant's app made with Laravel, and i have this [event here that should start every day at 4am](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1xwl.png)

The content of this event is nothing special:

```
UPDATE shipping_times SET shipping_times.available = shipping_times.max_quantity
```

Thing is, every night at midnight the **event scheduler variable** auto sets to **OFF** even if i do **GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON**.

This is quite a problem since the event is used to "replenish" available orders.

Since my event should occur at 4AM i don't think the problem is event-related.

What could it be?

Comment: Why you don't use Laravel Command to achieve that ? it's easy and clear.
Take a look here :
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#writing-commands

Comment: MySQL cannot disabe this variable by itself - so it receives according request. Enable General Log temporarily and detect the request for event scheduler disabling, then find and identify the connection which executes this statement and define the source.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve this problem? Is this even related to Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

## Alternative: Laravel Task Scheduling

Laravel Tasks come to mind for solving this instead: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling
*(other Laravel version docs available there as well)*

Adding recurring tasks in this way puts them all in one place instead of hidden somewhere in a menu. They are also independant of your elusive `event_scheduler`.

You can also use a command and call it from the task scheduling code. See BKF's comment.

### Are your events firing?

I am not sure but could it be true the event is only firing if you always have traffic between 00:00 and 04:00? Laravel Tasks also fire after the fact, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to my.cnf (or whaterver the config file is):

```
event_scheduler = ON
```

and restart mysqld.

Apparently, something is shutting down MySQL every night, perhaps a backup?  The above setting will turn it on each time it restarts.